# Correctly configuring Google Cloud DNS to access webserver via domain

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform

I have a webserver that I've created on a Google Cloud instance. I have assigned it a static IP address already, and I am able to access the server  by navigating directly to the IP.

I have a domain registered through Google Domains. I have set its nameservers to the following (these are Google Cloud's nameservers):

```
ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com
```

In Google Cloud DNS, I have the following records:

[image: Cloud DNS]

The redactions on the left are my domain name, and the redaction on the right is the external (static) IP address assigned to my server.

It's been about 12 hours since the records were added, so I suppose it's possible that the changes just haven't propagated yet. But when I do a `whois` on my domain name, I see the correct nameservers, and when I run `host` I get nothing returned at all. This suggests to me that there is a problem in my dns settings.

The NS and SOA records were added automatically by Google, while I manually added the two A records (there were no A records before, I selected the 1 day TTL because they were new records).

What, if anything, have I set or done incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding your A record to the base domain, you've created a subdomain named `@`.

A lone `@` has a special meaning in text-format zone files (indicating the base domain) and some web-based DNS record managers have cloned this behavior, but that **does not** necessarily extend to *all* such systems, nor to DNS as a whole.

Instead, many DNS management websites – including Google Cloud DNS – expect you to simply leave the subdomain field empty.

(How to recognize whether it worked or not? Only a *bare* `@` has the special meaning, but `@` combined with any other text doesn't. So when your resulting entry shows up as `@.example.net`, you can be sure it's gone wrong. Compare the appearance of your A and NS records.)

Comment: That's actually all it was, it looks like. I'm used to the @ being a stand-in for base domain like it is with many cheap consumer level dns services, it didn't even occur to me that I could leave that blank.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a matter of cheapness, just a design choice. (Most sites show tables which look just like a [standard zone file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file), so they also accept the same syntax as a zone file would... Probably the best option would to accept both `@` _and_ an empty value.)